# Dynamic Checkbox in php/html

Tags: php, html, mysql, dynamic, checkbox

I've written these lines of code in order to crate my dynamic(fetch data from a database) checkbox.

```
**<?php 

   db_connect();

   $sql = mysql_query('SELECT title  FROM products WHERE cname LIKE "Coffee"') or die(mysql_error());     

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_BOTH)){
       echo "<input type='checkbox' name='products[]' value='".$row['title']."'>"
        .$row['title'];
   }

?>**
```

The problem is that the results come in the same line in my webpage, but I'd like them to be appeared as a list so as to create an order-list /menu of me cafeteria.
How can I correct this?

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_BOTH)){
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='products[]' value='".$row['title']."'>"
     .$row['title'];
}
```

to

```
echo "<ul>\n":
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_BOTH)){
    echo "<li><input type='checkbox' name='products[]' value='".$row['title']."'>"
     .$row['title']."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>\n":
```

Comment: The same here! It is just transfered from the left to the right.

Comment: This would only appear inline if you had CSS that caused it to render that way,

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
<?php
db_connect();
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT title  FROM products WHERE cname LIKE "Coffee"') or     die(mysql_error());
echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_BOTH)){

echo "<li> <input type='checkbox' name='products[]' value='".$row['title']."'></li>"
    .$row['title'];}//end while

echo"</ul>";
```

Comment: I tried it but it only changed the align from left to the right part of the page but all my entries are still in the same line.

Comment: I'm sorry, and here the changes :D

Comment: Thanks but we still have problem! :/

Comment: Problem solved pals! I've just added "echo "<br />";" in my while loop. Sorry for this comment but I;m not allowed to answer my own question yet! Thanks a lot for you suggestions! :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, the *easiest* solution would be to add line breaks (`<br />`) after each row.

You could also use a table.  For example, something like:

```
<?php 
    echo '<table>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_BOTH)){
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='products[]' value='".$row['title']."'>";
        echo $row['title'];
        echho "</td></tr>";
   }
   echo '</table>'
?>
```

But there are better alternatives that involve `div`s and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in to a unordered list (UL):

```
<ul>
<?php 
db_connect();

$sql = mysql_query('SELECT title  FROM products WHERE cname LIKE "Coffee"') or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_BOTH)){
echo "<li><input type='checkbox' name='products[]' value='".$row['title']."'>"
    .$row['title']."</li>";}

?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

   db_connect();

   $sql = mysql_query('SELECT title  FROM products WHERE cname LIKE "Coffee"') or die(mysql_error());     

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_BOTH)){
       echo "<input type='checkbox' name='products[]' value='".$row['title']."'>"
        .$row['title']."<br/>";
   }

?>
```